# CAScrollLayer not working on Video

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, editing

I am trying to create image animation on Video with the help of `CAScrollLayer`  I am able to add images on `CAScrollLayer` but it's not scrolling when video is played any help will be appreciable  below is my code i have tried so far.

```
   CALayer *layer;

   // self.view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 460)];
   scrollLayer = [CAScrollLayer layer];
   scrollLayer.backgroundColor =  [[UIColor blackColor] CGColor];
   scrollLayer.bounds = parentLayer.bounds;
   scrollLayer.contentsRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, scrollLayer.bounds.size.width*images.count, scrollLayer.bounds.size.height);
   scrollLayer.borderWidth = 2.5;
   scrollLayer.borderColor = [[UIColor redColor] CGColor];
   scrollLayer.position = CGPointMake(self.view.center.x, self.view.center.y - 20);
   scrollLayer.scrollMode = kCAScrollHorizontally;
   scrollLayer.speed = 2.0;
   //  [self.view.layer addSublayer:scrollLayer];

   [parentLayer insertSublayer:scrollLayer atIndex:0];

   for(int i=0; i<[images count]; i++) {
      UIImage *image = [images objectAtIndex:i];
      layer = [CALayer layer];
      layer.backgroundColor = [[UIColor blackColor] CGColor];
      layer.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, 300);
      layer.contents = (id)[image CGImage];
      layer.position = CGPointMake(layer.bounds.size.width * i, self.view.center.y);

      // scrollLayer.speed = 2.0;

      [scrollLayer addSublayer:layer];
   }

   [parentLayer addSublayer:scrollLayer];
   [self performSelector:@selector(scrollPoint) withObject:nil   afterDelay:2.0];
   compostion.animationTool = [AVVideoCompositionCoreAnimationTool videoCompositionCoreAnimationToolWithPostProcessingAsVideoLayer:videoLayer inLayer:parentLayer];
```

Thank you.

Comment: please help required.anybody have any solution on this